# Mocking default SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, mockito, sharedpreferences

So I have a class that takes in a `Context` through the constructor, and grabs the default `SharedPreferences` from it using:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

I'm testing this class, and in my unit test I've written the following code to retrieve a mocked `SharedPreferences` instance when `getSharedPreferences(String, int)` is invoked:

```
Context context = mock(Context.class);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mock(SharedPreferences.class);

when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt()))
            .thenReturn(sharedPreferences);
when(sharedPreferences.getString(anyString(), nullable(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(tokenManager.getToken());
```

When I run the test for this class, it ends up with a `null` object instead of my mocked SharedPreferences instance. However, if I grab the `SharedPreferences` instance with `context.getSharedPreferences("stubbed", 123)`, I end up with my mocked `SharedPreferences` code.

So why does `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` return `null` instance while directly calling `getSharedPreferences` on my mock `Context` returns my mocked `SharedPreferences` instance?

Comment: did you check the code of `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`? How does the PM get the data from the `context`?

Comment: `return context.getSharedPreferences(getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context), getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode());``

Answer (score 0):

Based on this document (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests) and debugging the code line by line, the conclusion I've reached about why this occurs is because the android code used for unit tests in gradle is actually just a shell that returns stubbed values on every method invocation, so naturally that leads me to assume that the code for `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` that's being used in my unit tests is more or less `return null`.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to mock the static call to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`. This is not possible at the moment with mockito, there is still [discussion going on the corresponding issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013).

One solution is shown in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito), you could check [PowerMock](http://www.powermock.org/) or [JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io) as alternatives